# Need Activity Reference In Android JobScheduler To Initialize SQLite ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I'm writing my first Android app.

I'm trying to use JobScheduler to periodically read entries from my SQLite DB. I have implemented a ContentProvider to hide the SQLite details from the user.

I need an activity reference to initialize the ContentProvider's content resolver. I have been unable to figure out how to get an activity reference to my JobService.

Is there any way to specify the activity in either JobInfo or JobParameters, or some other way to obtain the activity reference I need to initialize my content resolver?

Comment: You don't need an `Activity` specifically. You just need a `Context`, and a `JobService` is a `Context`.

Comment: I've re-coded my ContentProvider to init with a Context instead of an activity and it works. Thanks!